# Render divIcon of one marker instead of cluster marker

Tags: leaflet.markercluster

I'm trying to render only one (div)Icon of a marker instead of cluster marker:

```
iconCreateFunction: createClusterIcon(cluster) {
    return cluster.getAllChildMarkers()[0].getIcon()
}
```

I don't have any ideas as there are no errors shown.
In the example iconCreateFunction works as follows:

```
return L.divIcon({html: '<b>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</b>'});
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is impossible, however I've found a workaround. It may be helpful for someone.

When creating a marker I pass ion the options all the data needed for rendering an icon:

```
L.marker([Lat, Lng], {
    // other marker options go here,
    sourceData: {
        // data that I need for rendering the icon
    }
})
```

and then in `iconCreateFunction` I simply render the icon again with data obtained from the marker:

```
const markersData = cluster.getAllChildMarkers()             // all markers of the cluster
        .filter(markerData => markerData.options.sourceData) // get only markers with sourceData specified

markersData[0] // contains the data of the first of the markers
```

It allows me to pick one of the markers basing on the data.

---

If I don't want to render an icon again, I can just pass some id to the child DivIcon of my marker when creating it

```
var myIcon = L.divIcon({html: '<div data-icon-id="123123"></div>'});
```

And later `iconCreateFunction` just grab it from the DOM:

```
cont html = document.querySelector(`[data-icon-id="123123"]`).outerHTML

return L.divIcon({html})
```